# how can i get which month a given year day is in in php?

Tags: php, datetime, posix

I have been given year day (1-366) and I need to figure out which month it is in, how can I do this?
Well, I actually have a date string like : year, day or year, minute of day, second and I ultimately want to create a POSIX timestamp from it, how can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$year=2013;
$d=360;
echo date("m",strtotime("1/1/$year + $d days")) 
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have PHP >= 5.3, then you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

```
$day = 176;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('z', $day);
echo $date->getTimestamp();  // 1372275280
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the date function to get a posix time stamp.

To get the month of a certain date, use intval(date('m'), mktime($h,$m,$s,$month,$day,$year))